# How to i use "Mirror Under The Door" option as a Player in Swat4

Tags: pc, swat-4

In **Swat4** Game As a boss I order other 4 members to do some tasks like "**Move**", "**Fall-in**", "**Open and Clear**"..etc.
One of the command is **"Mirror Under The Door"**. when i used this command one of the player will check under the door. 
Is this Command For reserved that Players only?
Or Can i used this command Myself and i check under door?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is a command that you can give to the team but cannot perform yourself. So you only know if there are enemies after the door, but not the actual location

Comment: Ok. So i can receive only voices from team members.. like "Suspect Inside" or "No suspect inside". @Softability

Comment: I think I remember being able to use the door mirror myself, actually.

Answer (score 2):

You just click on your keyboard 9 or F9.

And to use grenades YOURSELF just press 3 for flashbang 4 for i think gas and 5 for i think stun

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Writing "I think" does not actually support your statement, please provide answers when you are sure

Comment: And why are you mentioning grenades in the first place? However, you are right about equipping the optiwand in SWAT4.

Answer (score 1):

The **"Mirror under the door"** command makes one of the AI which has the **[Optiwand](https://swat-4.fandom.com/wiki/Optiwand)** equipped use it to check under door.

You can add or remove the Optiwand from your and/or the AIs loadouts during briefing (it is in your and (I think) Red and Blue leads loadouts by default). Mid-mission, you can manually equip the Optiwand by pressing 9. Alternatively, when looking down on a door, a prompt telling you to hold left-click (or whatever your "Fire" button is) to mirror under the door should come up on the bottom middle.